# Not able to find minimum date for nested array of object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, object

I have nested array of object. I want to find minimum date from the object. but which one is best way to find minimum date from market object's FromDate inside array of market.

sometimes it might be object or array of object. need to check region is array or object.

It might be an issue to find that it has value or not.

Here is JS code:-

```
{
  "Products": {
    "Product": {
      "ProductId": "8",
      "ProductName": "Woven Yarn",
      "CreatedDate": "2017-04-20T17:04:07.4",
      "Subproducts": {
        "SubProduct": [{
          "SubProductId": "3",
          "SubProductName": "10/1 Carded",
          "CreatedDate": "2017-04-20T17:04:14.36",
          "Regions": {
            "Region": [{
              "RegionId": "1",
              "RegionName": "Asia",
              "CreatedDate": "2017-04-20T17:04:27.03",
              "Markets": {
                "Market": [{
                    "MarketId": "1~10",
                    "MarketName": "FOB China",
                    "FromDate": "2015-01-01T00:00:00",
                    "CreatedDate": "2015-01-01T00:00:00"
                  },
                  {
                    "MarketId": "1~44",
                    "MarketName": "FOB Pakistan",
                    "FromDate": "2015-01-01T00:00:00",
                    "CreatedDate": "2015-01-01T00:00:00"
                  },
                  {
                    "MarketId": "1~50",
                    "MarketName": "FOB West India",
                    "FromDate": "2015-01-01T00:00:00",
                    "CreatedDate": "2015-01-01T00:00:00"
                  },
                  {
                    "MarketId": "3~44",
                    "MarketName": "CNF Pakistan",
                    "FromDate": "2021-01-04T00:00:00",
                    "CreatedDate": "2021-01-04T00:00:00"
                  }
                ]
              }
            }]
          }
        }]
      },
      "Regions": {
        "Region": [{
          "RegionId": "1",
          "RegionName": "Asia",
          "CreatedDate": "2017-04-20T17:04:27.03",
          "Markets": {
            "Market": [{
                "MarketId": "1~10",
                "MarketName": "FOB China",
                "FromDate": "2015-01-01T00:00:00",
                "CreatedDate": "2015-01-01T00:00:00"
              },
              {
                "MarketId": "1~44",
                "MarketName": "FOB Pakistan",
                "FromDate": "2015-01-01T00:00:00",
                "CreatedDate": "2015-01-01T00:00:00"
              },
              {
                "MarketId": "1~50",
                "MarketName": "FOB West India",
                "FromDate": "2015-01-01T00:00:00",
                "CreatedDate": "2015-01-01T00:00:00"
              },
              {
                "MarketId": "3~44",
                "MarketName": "CNF Pakistan",
                "FromDate": "2021-01-04T00:00:00",
                "CreatedDate": "2021-01-04T00:00:00"
              }
            ]
          }
        }]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My Code:-

```
if (res && res.Data && res.Data.Products) {
  if (res.Data.Products != null && res.Data.Products != undefined &&
    res.Data.Products.Product != null && res.Data.Products.Product != undefined &&
    res.Data.Products.Product.Subproducts != undefined) {
    if (res.Data.Products.Product.Subproducts.SubProduct.length != undefined) {
      if (res.Data.Products.Product.Subproducts.SubProduct.Regions.Region) {

      } else {

      }
      console.log(res.Data.Products.Product.Subproducts.SubProduct);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Use recursion

This allows you to cope with any structure combining objects and arrays.

In JS, both objects and arrays return `object` when you use the `typeof` operator. Since in both cases the `Object.values()` of the object or array will give you the elements, you can use this to your advantage: you don't need to know whether each stage of the nesting is an object or an array.

Here is an example.

```js
res = {
  Data: {
    "Products": {
      "Product": {
        "ProductId": "8",
        "ProductName": "Woven Yarn",
        "CreatedDate": "2017-04-20T17:04:07.4",
        "Subproducts": {
          "SubProduct": [{
            "SubProductId": "3",
            "SubProductName": "10/1 Carded",
            "CreatedDate": "2017-04-20T17:04:14.36",
            "Regions": {
              "Region": [{
                "RegionId": "1",
                "RegionName": "Asia",
                "CreatedDate": "2017-04-20T17:04:27.03",
                "Markets": {
                  "Market": [{
                      "MarketId": "1~10",
                      "MarketName": "FOB China",
                      "FromDate": "2015-01-01T00:00:00",
                      "CreatedDate": "2015-01-01T00:00:00"
                    },
                    {
                      "MarketId": "1~44",
                      "MarketName": "FOB Pakistan",
                      "FromDate": "2015-01-01T00:00:00",
                      "CreatedDate": "2015-01-01T00:00:00"
                    },
                    {
                      "MarketId": "1~50",
                      "MarketName": "FOB West India",
                      "FromDate": "2015-01-01T00:00:00",
                      "CreatedDate": "2015-01-01T00:00:00"
                    },
                    {
                      "MarketId": "3~44",
                      "MarketName": "CNF Pakistan",
                      "FromDate": "2021-01-04T00:00:00",
                      "CreatedDate": "2021-01-04T00:00:00"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }]
            }
          }]
        },
        "Regions": {
          "Region": [{
            "RegionId": "1",
            "RegionName": "Asia",
            "CreatedDate": "2017-04-20T17:04:27.03",
            "Markets": {
              "Market": [{
                  "MarketId": "1~10",
                  "MarketName": "FOB China",
                  "FromDate": "2015-01-01T00:00:00",
                  "CreatedDate": "2015-01-01T00:00:00"
                },
                {
                  "MarketId": "1~44",
                  "MarketName": "FOB Pakistan",
                  "FromDate": "2015-01-01T00:00:00",
                  "CreatedDate": "2015-01-01T00:00:00"
                },
                {
                  "MarketId": "1~50",
                  "MarketName": "FOB West India",
                  "FromDate": "2015-01-01T00:00:00",
                  "CreatedDate": "2015-01-01T00:00:00"
                },
                {
                  "MarketId": "3~44",
                  "MarketName": "CNF Pakistan",
                  "FromDate": "2021-01-04T00:00:00",
                  "CreatedDate": "2021-01-04T00:00:00"
                }
              ]
            }
          }]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

function recursiveEarliestDate(obj, earliestDateSoFar = null) {

  if ("FromDate" in obj && (obj.FromDate < earliestDateSoFar || !earliestDateSoFar)) {
    earliestDateSoFar = obj.FromDate
  }

  Object.values(obj).forEach(value => {
    if (typeof value === "object") {
      const childEarliestDate = recursiveEarliestDate(value, earliestDateSoFar);
      if (childEarliestDate < earliestDateSoFar || !earliestDateSoFar) {
        earliestDateSoFar = childEarliestDate
      }
    }
  })

  return earliestDateSoFar
}


console.log(recursiveEarliestDate(res))
```

Comment: This is what I want, thanks buddy, Actually, I  have tried it but not working. your answer is accurate what i want... thanks for saving my time buddy